# how to create Model Class in JavaScript, & parse the JSON to that class type?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongoose, model

in Node-Express-Mongo app, how to create a **Model Class** (ES6) like below code snippet ??

```
class Profile { name: String, age: Number, address: Address }
```

and **want to parse the incoming request JSON body into the above Class Type**...

if i use Mongoose driver for MongoDB, I can create Class from Schema like below code snippet,

```
const Profile = mongoose.model('Profile', new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 30
},
age: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    max: 100
},
address: addressSchema
}))
```

but I prefer native mongodb driver, I don't want to use Mongoose.

Comment: Why do you _"want to parse the incoming request JSON body into the above Class Type"_?

Comment: In ES6 you there is no type checking except if you use Flow.js or use Typescript. Also ES6 support public attribute only not no native private and protected attribute accessors. You can achieve private by wrapping the class inside another closure to simulate private attribute accessor though.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I think he has some methods in profile. He don't want to  have a generic JS anonymous object data only

Comment: then only I can create Profile Object and I will save into MongoDB, @Aluan

Comment: @Bhuvanesh the MongoDb driver just wants an object and that's something you already have.

Comment: You have to test the response once you've parsed it. Not sure how a class would help you with that.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Ofcourse, MongoDb driver just wants only an object. how can i check whether the client is sending correct property name or data type I want to store ??; client may change "name" prop to "fullName" & send age value as String instead of Number... I don't want to store a generic JS anonymous object into DB. if I have a class template I can easily know what property & data type the client r sending....

Comment: @Bhuvanesh why do you think that? Classes are not types and using them does not provide any validation.

Comment: so if i want to use native MongoDB driver with class template (property name & its type).. I have to use TypeScript.. no other way Right ??

Comment: @Bhuvanesh that still won't help you if the API and its client drift apart. You need to determine what is valid and test it explicitly.

Comment: Not sure why you want to create a class for `Schema`. To create a model class, its a simple as `const User = mongoose.model('users');`